# Regex not working as expected for html tags

Tags: java, regex

I am not able to write some regex for following scenarios.

1 : `This is <b>My Text</b> some other <b> </b> text as well <b></b><b>non empty tag1</b> other text`.

**Expected output :** `some other <b> </b> text as well <b></b>`

2 : `This is <b>My Text</b> some other <b> </b> text as well <b></b><b>non empty tag2</b> other text`.

**Expected output :** `some other <b> </b> text as well <b></b>`

Here, if you have noticed the text **My Text** is fix (static) but the second non empty tag value may vary. The regex should be able to extract the text between the `<b>My Text</b>` and the first occurrence non empty `<b>` tag after that.

I have already tried lot myself but not able to achieve the same. Waiting for some responses.

**UPDATE :**
My attempt is  given below.

```
    String BOLD_START_TAG = "(\\<b\\>)";
    String BOLD_END_TAG = "(\\<\\/b\\>)";
    StringBuffer regexBuffer = new StringBuffer("^(.*)")
                    .append(BOLD_START_TAG)
                    .append(regex)
                    .append(BOLD_END_TAG)
                    .append("(.*)")
                    .append(BOLD_START_TAG)
                    .append(nextElementString)
                    .append(BOLD_END_TAG)
                    .append("(.*)$");
 String regex = regexBuffer.toString();
 System.out.println(myText.replaceAll(regex, "$5"));
```

Comment: [Obligatory warning](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Comment: What regular expressions have you tried, and how did they fail?

Comment: Sadly, pretty much any question saying regex and html is going to get some downvotes

Comment: if you don't know the answer, please don't devote the question. you can always suggest other way of asking question rather than just devote, if you feel it's not right.

Comment: You make quite the assumption by saying _if you don't know the answer, [...]_. You'll notice, if you hover over the vote buttons, that it states _This question [...] is not useful._ That's likely what's going on here. Don't parse HTML with regular expression.

Comment: but sometimes person need it anyhow, so I asked for help if possible. I am also aware the what is recommended and what is not.

Comment: Ask what you want, but don't be surprised when users downvote if they don't think it's useful. And definitely don't ask them not to downvote.

Comment: `<` and `>` are not special characters in regex so you don't need to escape them. And do you really need to use regex? What if there is simpler solution but it would require using some additional library like Jsoup or builtin XML parser?

Comment: Also what do you mean by non-empty `<b>` tag? Is `<b> </b>` empty (there is space inside it)? Or `<b><i> </i></b>` empty (there is another tag inside it)?

Comment: For a good explanation of why you are going to end up impairing your software if you try to use regex to parse HTML or XML, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/701166/can-you-provide-some-examples-of-why-it-is-hard-to-parse-xml-and-html-with-a-reg .

Comment: @Pshemo, I am already using Jsoup, but not able to achieve that as well, that's why I have decided to go with Regex.

Comment: Please have a look with Jsoup Question : http://stackoverflow.com/q/37692739/1326692

Answer (score 1):

**This is a dirty solution** It's not really parsing html, it's only coping with a small subset of it. *Only suitable for quick and dirty hacking*. For example this regexp assumes the `<b>` and `</b>` all occur on the same line.

The examples in your question look the same? But anyhow, how about:

`/<b>My Text<\/b>(.*?)<b>.*\w+<\/b>/`

Note that you can't really parse html with regexp. You can only hope to cope with a small subset of cases.

*Edit*: Added a lazy `.*?` matcher in the middle to cope with the case where multiple `<b>` tags appear on one line.

Comment: Hi Thanks for atleast answer.. but it seems it's not working in my case, because it may be possible that I have some other non-empty b tags as well, so in your case it will give me all the text between My Text and the last non-empty tag :(

Comment: Right - in that case you want a lazy modifier in there ```.*?```, I'll fix the example.