# Not able to achieve something with Jsoup HTML parser Java

Tags: java, html, html-parsing, jsoup

I am not able to parse some text for following scenarios using Jsoup Java Library.

1 : `This is <b>My Text</b> some other <b> </b> text as well <b></b><b>non empty tag1</b> other text`.

**Expected output :** `some other <b> </b> text as well <b></b>`

2 : `This is <b>My Text</b> some other <b> </b> text as well <b></b><b>non empty tag2</b> other text`.

**Expected output :** `some other <b> </b> text as well <b></b>`

3 : `This is <b>My Text</b> some other <b> </b> text as well <b></b><b>non empty tag2</b> other text <b></b> <b>non empty tag3</b>`.

**Expected output :** `some other <b> </b> text as well <b></b>`

Here, if you have noticed the text **My Text** is fix (static) but the second non empty (don't consider space as value)  B tag  value may vary. The regex should be able to extract the text between the `<b>My Text</b>` and the first occurrence non empty `<b>` tag after that.

I am using Jsoup library, but not able to achieve the above expected output. Please make sure that solution should be common for each scenario, because it's dynamic in my case.

Comment: Can `non empty tag2` be only `<b>` tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple solution could look like

- find `<b>` element which you are interested in (the one with text you are looking for)
- iterate over siblings placed after it and print them until you find non empty `<b>`

You just need to remember that Jsoup is using `Node` to store all elements (including text which doesn't belong to tags), while `Element` class (which extends `Node`) may contain only specific tags.

So for instance text like

```
before <b>bold</b> after<i>italic</i>
```

will be represented as

```
<node>before </node>
<element tag="B">
   <node>bold</node>
</element>
<node> after</node>
<element tag="I">
   <node>italic</node>
</element>
```

So if for instance you `select("b")` (which will find `<element tab="B">`) and call `nextElementSibling()` it will move you to `<element tag="I">`. To get `<node>after</node>` you will need to use `nextSibling()` which doesn't eliminate simple text nodes.

Possible problem with `Node` class is that it doesn't provide `text()` method which can generate textual content of current node (which could allow us to test if current node/element has any text). But nothing stops us from casting `Node` which handles tag to `Element` which provides such method.

So our solution could look like:

```
public static String findFragment(String html, String fixedStart) {

    Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);
    Element myBTag = doc
            .select("b:matches(^" + Pattern.quote(fixedStart) + "$)")
            .first();

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    boolean foundNonEmpty = false;

    Node currentSibling = myBTag.nextSibling();
    while (currentSibling != null && !foundNonEmpty) {
        if (currentSibling.nodeName().equals("b")) {
            Element b = (Element) currentSibling;
            if (!b.text().trim().isEmpty())
                foundNonEmpty = true;
        }
        sb.append(currentSibling.toString());
        currentSibling = currentSibling.nextSibling();
    }

    return sb.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
      String html = "This is <b>My Text</b> some other <b> </b> text as well <b></b><b>non empty tag1</b> other text";
      System.out.println(getTargetText(html));
      html = "This is <b>My Text</b> some other <b> </b> text as well <b></b><b>non empty tag2</b> other text";
      System.out.println(getTargetText(html));
      html = "This is <b>My Text</b> some other <b> </b> text as well <b></b><b>non empty tag2</b> other text <b></b> <b>non empty tag3</b>";
      System.out.println(getTargetText(html));
    }

    public static String getTargetText(String html) {
      Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);
      Elements bTags = doc.getElementsByTag("b");
      Element startBTag = null;
      Element endBTag = null;

      for (int i = 0; i < bTags.size(); i++) {
        Element bTag = bTags.get(i);
        String text = bTag.text().trim(); // use html() instead of text() if you want to match nested inner tags.
        if (startBTag == null && text.equals("My Text")) {
          startBTag = bTag;
        }
        if (startBTag != null && text.startsWith("non empty tag")) { // here you can use regex match if you want
          endBTag = bTag;
          break;
        }
      }

      if (endBTag != null) {
        String startString = startBTag.outerHtml();
        String endString = endBTag.outerHtml();
        int startIndex = html.indexOf(startString);
        if (startIndex >= 0) {
          int endIndex = html.indexOf(endString, startIndex + startString.length());
          if (endIndex >= 0) {
            return html.substring(startIndex + startString.length(), endIndex);
          }
        }
      }
      return null;
    }
```

output:

```
     some other <b> </b> text as well <b></b>
     some other <b> </b> text as well <b></b>
     some other <b> </b> text as well <b></b>
```

Comment: Almost but it looks like ending non-empty-tag can have any test (it is dynamic). So your `if (startBTag != null && text.startsWith("non empty tag"))` should be `else if (startBTag != null && !text.trim().isEmpty())` (`else` part was added to make sure that we are not checking and handling same tag which we used in previous `if` which handled setting `startBTag` since starting tag can't be same as ending tag).

Comment: Also `for (int i = 0; i < bTags.size(); i++) { Element bTag = bTags.get(i); ...}` can be replaced with `for (Element bTag : bTags){...}` since you are not using `i` anywhere else in that loop.